# `INSTALLED_APPS` from django's setting.py is not able to find my own pip package even though it is installed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pip

I have created a pip package for my DRF application. I have tested the APIs of this package and it is working fine. Now I have decided to put it on PyPi so that my friends can also use it.

This is how I uploaded my package to PyPi. (please note I already have an account on PyPi)

1. Created source distribution - `python setup.py sdist`
2. Check Manifest - `check-manifest --create`. Here I have made sure that all the module of my app are in the source distribution tar.
3. The I created build distribution - `python setup.py bdist_wheel sdit`. `wheel` was already installed in my env.
4. Then I installed twine and uploaded it to PyPi using command - `twine upload --skip-existing dist/*`

Now to test this uploaded PyPi package I started a new Django Restframework project and installed it using `pip install <package>`. However when I mentioned it in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` it return this error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named`.

I have also check the virtual environment for the package at `lib/python3.9/site-packages/` and yes I found the folder for my package.

Where could I have possible went wrong. This is very weird problem.

Comment: did you configure it as a [Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)? You'll need to have an `apps.py` module inside your package and include some metadata (such as the name) so Django can find it.

Comment: I have the `apps.py` in the package but could you help understand where and how should I write this metadata

Comment: Have you subclassed [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig) inside of your `apps.py`?

Comment: That's good, how are you writing the dotted path to the module in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? And is the package you're looking for present in a `pip list`?

Comment: Seems like you're missing an `__init__.py` in the `django_restframework_2fa/` directory in your package

Comment: Problem is solved thank you very much @khuynh for your time.